# Why does my extremely basic CSS code produce different outputs on jsFiddle and jsBin?

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle, jsbin

Two different outputs, but exactly the same super-basic code:

**CSS**

```
input {
  display: block;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Register" />
```

produces the following output on *jsFiddle* (live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WLpRE/)),

[image]

but this output in *jsBin* (live demo [here](http://jsbin.com/amemil/1/edit))

[image]

I have tested this in latest Firefox and Chrome (same differences everywhere).
In a plain naked .html file, it looks like on jsBin btw...

Comment: btw jsfiddle is veeery slow currently... :(

Comment: http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/jsfiddle.net.html#commentstop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is the doctype.

From JS Bin (no doctype):

```
<html>
```

From jsFiddle (html5 doctype):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The lack of a doctype on JS Bin is throwing the browser into [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).  Apparently quirks mode and standards mode use a different default value for the box-sizing property.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks. I could reproduce this locally with a basic html file, with and without `<!doctype html>`. It's exactly like you said.

Answer (score 5):

Two reasons:

1. Tools like these apply a [CSS reset](http://sixrevisions.com/css/a-comprehensive-guide-to-css-resets/) to their content to reduce
   variability caused by browser defaults. Different tools will apply
   different defaults
2. The specific difference seems to be the [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property. Jsfiddle is going with `box-sizing: content-box;` while
   Jsbin is going with `box-sizing: border-box;`

`content-box` takes the width, then adds the padding - hence the extra width. `border-box;` includes the padding (and border) in the width.

You can see what's going on if you open up a debugging tool like Firebug (or Inspect Element), target the input box, and look at the Layout tab (or equivalent).

---

As a side note, I can't see exactly where the `box-sizing` settings are coming from - it looks like they're not being set directly but are being applied as a result of another setting. Either that or I just can't find them... either way `box-sizing` is rather experimental, I wouldn't be surprised if they're fixed and giving the same result as expected in a few months.

Comment: Those setting seems to come "from HTML5" by setting the doctype to html5. To sum your answer up, this css rule will fix this issue: `box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 1):

jsBin is of course showing the correct/expected output.

I can't say why jsFiddle extends the input fields in that way - I cannot even view it, you said it was slow, the website won't even load for me at the moment.

Perhaps their current issues are greater than just slow/unavailability.

If I were you I'd just use jsBin for now and not worry about it.

Edit:
user568458's answer is better. I can't comment, but I think box-sizing takes a default value from the version of javascript - selectable in jsFiddle not sure about jsBin.

Assuming this is true, I can say for sure 1.9.2 adds padding to a given width - had me stumped for a good thirty minutes when it messed with my Wordpress layout.