# HTML Input Button

Tags: html, forms, button, onclick

I'm using this code here:

```
<input type="button"  value="Latest Results" onClick="self.location='http://URL.COM/SEARCH STRING'+document.getElementById('code').value +'EXTRA BIT OF SEARCH URL'">
```

Which I'm using with an input box (sometime several input boxes) to take an input and quickly add it to a URL to search an internal system. It works great for what we need, but I'm trying to get it to open in a new window rather than the current one.

I've tried adding target="_blank" to the end and changing onClick="self.location= to window.open but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried use window.open instead of self.location?

Comment: check this: http://jsbin.com/ocoqid/1/

Comment: Try `<input type="button"  value="Latest Results" onClick="window.open('http://URL.COM/SEARCH STRING'+document.getElementById('code').value +'EXTRA BIT OF SEARCH URL', '_blank')">`

Comment: @PiLHA `window.open` as its second parameter has default `_blank` :P

Comment: @PiLHA check this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui yay, another fellow coder who likes w3schools.com :)

Comment: @pattyd YEAH! I found only you in favour of w3schools :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="button"  value="Latest Results" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com');">
```

Use `window.open` instead of `self.location` :)

[jsBin.](http://jsbin.com/ocoqid/1/)

Comment: You should use JSfiddle instead of jsBin... it has a much nicer interface, so that the OP can see what is actually going on

Comment: @pattyd it have! let me give you an example difference :)

Comment: ah- I didn't try window.open and brackets. That's what I wanted- thank you.

Comment: @pattyd check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493145/why-does-my-extremely-basic-css-code-produce-different-outputs-on-jsfiddle-and-j