# window.open as tabs not pop ups in Chrome

Tags: javascript, window.open

I've been using an adapted version of this code:

[HTML Input Buttom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493404/html-input-buttom)

I've adapted it to have one button to search multiple sites..

```
<script>
function multiSearch(){
window.open (SEARCH URL A);
window.open (SEARCH URL B);
window.open (SEARCH URL B);
</script>

<input type="button"  value="Latest Results" onClick="multiSearch;">
```

Which works fine but in Chrome only first Search window opens as a new tab, the other two open as pop ups. Is there anyway to get them all to open as tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.open(url, '_blank')` sometimes opens in a new tab, but usually in a new window depending on how it is used. You cannot control it directly using Javascript unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try..if it doesn't work I'll go back to the original code.